# how to detect how many same object is in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have one NSArray and I want get how many certain object is it?

this is my code:

```
NSArray *filter = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"2",@"3",@"2",@"3", nil];

switch (section) {
      case 0:
          //check how many 1 object is filter array
          return //number of 1 object
          break;
      case 1:
          //check how many 2 object is filter array
          return //number of 2 object
          break;
      case 2:
          //check how many 3 object is filter array
          return //number of 3 object
          break;
}
```

please guide me about it.

Comment: What constitutes a "duplicate" - Is it specific objects or are they distinct objects for which `isEqual` returns true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to use: `NSCountedSet`

```
NSCountedSet *filter = [NSCountedSet setWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"2",@"3",@"2",@"3", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", @([filter countForObject:@"2"])); // Outputs 3
```

If you already have the array you can do: `[NSCountedSet setWithArray:array]`

Comment: This will only work if there are multiple instances of the same object.  `NSCountedSet` does not take `isEqual` into consideration.  For example, it will work correctly for the string literals shown in the question, but won't work for arbitrary NSStrings even if they contain the same value

Comment: @Paulw11: Are you sure about that? I made a test with 2 (different) strings with the same contents, and that gave a counted set with one object (and count=2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSPredicate`:

```
switch (section) {
      case 0:
          NSArray *ones = [filter filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF = %@", @"1"]];
         return [ones count];
      case 1:
      //and so on
```

By the way, you don't need a `break` after the `return` statement inside of `switch`. The method will return, so the following cases won't be reach anyway.